# Vue.js not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting started with `Vue` but I am having trouble with rendering. I'm following this tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_getting_started). So far this is all I did in the app

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

But this is not rendering and why I added. I still see the same original rendering from when I first create the app. using `vue create mod-todo-vue`. I do not understand why. I even thought that maybe the server wasn't watching my files for changes but I restarted it and to my surprise it still shows the original web app rendering as if I didn't make any changes at all. Please someone help I would really like to move on from this part.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Vue did have this problem sometime, you can run build again. Then restart the server again.

Comment: How can I rebuild it. Plus, I have tried restarting by creating separate projects all having the same issue

Comment: One more thing, did you clean the history in your browser?

Comment: No I did not. Also why would this be needed?

Comment: Okay, this is very weird works when I go into incognito mode!!! Why is this the case. This doesn't seem that great? I can't delete my history each time this is not good.

Comment: Also, how can I fix this so that I don't have to clean my history each time?

Comment: I also think it doesn't a good idea to delete the history in the chrome. HMR will tell chrome to fetach new content when you update the source file, but the function is limited. You should figure out what chrome render for you. Cache? New content? Who knows!

Comment: You can prepare two browsers to avoid this. One for test, another for daily life.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running it with `npm run serve`? The situation is indeed a bit strange but first of all go to the devtools of your browser (F12) to the Network tab and make sure "Disable cache" is checked, then try again. If it doesn't work, with this setup it looks like a bug on vue-cli side. You can try vite to scaffold your project, too.

Comment: I am developing vue project with `vite` and it was great. Maybe `vite` can handle this gracefully.

Comment: Although if you see some stuff happening in the console after you saved your changes then it's unlikely this is an issue with tooling but rather something wrong with your browser. You can also try checking the docs of Vue, the tutorial on MDN uses some kind of custom template for creating a project, I doubt it's special in any way but still, it's not the official one.

Comment: Yeah, works when I empty cache although I can't disable it for some reason. I had to empty it and will have to do this each time. Good news is that it now shows the updated code each time I save my files. But if I refresh goes back to the previous thing I did right after emptying my cache. Same issue with both chrome and safari for me